# Javascript scroll to bottom of results within a scrolling page

Tags: javascript

If i search for something on this website
http://www.192.com/all/search/

It loads the first 20 results and i have to scroll down and wait for it to load. then scroll down again until it loads all results and can no longer scroll down. how can i do this using javascript. This is what i have so far

```
loop(100) {
wait(1)
run javascript("window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
scrolldelay = setTimeout(\'pageScroll()\',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds")
wait(1)
}
```

Comment: What language is your code running in? The one that's calling the Javascript code.

Comment: This is for a software this has a function to run a javas cript code. So it is not in any specific format that i know of as it uses a Node feature

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do some data mining/scraping. Why not use their REST API? I didn't find any documentation, but check out the requests your browser makes as you scroll down, and see the URLs and their respective responses.

Comment: I cant see any request that it is making. ie nothing like ?page=1  or nothing like that. so i am slightly confused.

Comment: Well I tried a sample request and got `http://www.192.com/rest/ajaxhtml/search/?sk=2673eb97-aebc-467a-b1e7-7aad2cbb0ef5&availability=unavailable&tab=people&resultsperpage=1&page=80-99&_=1399673568388` and `http://www.192.com/rest/ajaxhtml/search/?sk=2673eb97-aebc-467a-b1e7-7aad2cbb0ef5&availability=unavailable&tab=people&resultsperpage=1&page=100-146&_=1399673569451`, etc... You will see this in the network tab of your browser's developers tools ([Chrome](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-UqOBWra7pBs/TWaioJ1gPSI/AAAAAAAAADU/xB2gVMWYTSc/s1600/Screen%2Bshot%2B2011-02-24%2Bat%2B10.25.04%2BAM.png)).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to detect when you've scrolled to the bottom of the container, here's an example:

```
$('.container').on('scroll', function(e) {
    var offset = 100;
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + offset >= $(this).height()) {
        // Code to make an ajax request to append new content here
    }
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/bmYKc/**